# Differences between DATA INFILE and LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql

What are the differences between LOAD DATA INFILE and LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Comment: RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` gets the file from the database server's local filesystem. The file has to be located in the database directory or have world read permissions, and the client username must have the `FILE` privilege.

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` reads the file on the client, and sends the contents to the server.

You can find more details in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 7):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> If LOCAL **is** specified, the file is read by the client program on the **client host** and sent to the server.
>
> If LOCAL is **not** specified, the file must be located on the **server host** and is read directly by the server.

If you include the `LOCAL` keyword, MySQL will look for the file to load locally, and if you omit `LOCAL` then it will attempt to find it on the server.