# load records into mysql table from csv

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-server

I'm running mysql v8.0.24 on ubuntu server.  I have created a table called uranium in the database stocks.  I'm now trying to run the command below in mysql as root, to load records from a csv on the server into the table.  I'm getting the error below, does anyone see what the issue might be and can you suggest how to fix it?

code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user/uranium.csv' INTO TABLE stocks.uranium FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

error:

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Comment: Does LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE help? "LOCAL"

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL has [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) set, which restricts the directories that it will access for INFILE and OUTFILE operations. You can set the MySQL configuration to allow a nominated folder by editing the `[mysqld]` section of mysql.cnf<sup>*</sup>.

Ubuntu also has AppArmor running, that will prevent MySQL from seeing the file even if it has the correct permissions. You will need to update that too.

For this reason I recommend you create a dedicated directory for this sort of import, rather than using a home directory. For the purposes of this answer I have use `/sqlfiles`.

For Ubuntu and other Debian derived versions of Linux, go to `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d`
Using your favourite editor, edit the file `mysql.cnf` that you find there. (There are other files with the same name elsewhere in the /etc/mysql directory. Make sure you're editing the correct one)

At the end of the `[mysqld]` section add the line

```
secure-file-priv=/sqlfiles
```

Save the file, then create the folder and set the ownership to mysql

```
sudo mkdir /sqlfiles
sudo chown mysql:mysql /sqlfiles
```

Now update the AppArmor profile. Go to `/etc/apparmor.d/local` and edit the file `usr.sbin.mysqld`. Add these lines to the end of that file:

```
/sqlfiles/ r,
/sqlfiles/** rwk,
```

Finally, restart AppArmor

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

This is working on my development server running Ubuntu 20.04, MySQL 8.0.24

Good luck!

<sup>* If you create the entry in `mysql.cnf` but leave the filename blank you will disable the effect of the variable, and MySQL will read or write to any folder. AppArmor will still prevent access unless you update that too.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293413/differences-between-data-infile-and-load-data-local-infile)

In spite the fact that your csv file is located on the server's file system, I think you should include `LOCAL` keyword:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...
```

Or

> The file has to be located in the database directory or have world
> read permissions, and the client username must have the FILE
> privilege.

I think your csv file is not

> ...located in the database directory or have world read permissions...

Note that

> ...client username must have the FILE privilege...

MySql8 documentation: [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-local) and [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

> LOAD DATA INFILE gets the file from the database server's local
> filesystem. The file has to be located in the database directory or
> have world read permissions, and the client username must have the
> FILE privilege.
>
> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE reads the file on the client, and sends the
> contents to the server.
>
> You can find more details in the documentation.

And

> ```
> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server.
>
> If LOCAL is not specified, the file must be located on the server host and is read directly by the server.
> ```

Credit goes to [barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) and [tim-biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen)