# MySQL workbench not importing all rows from csv

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a CSV file to a new table in MySql. The file has 1 million rows but MySql is only importing 847 rows.

1. I tried saving the CSV file and importing various formats, utf-8, windows-1205, etc.
2. The CSV file has an INDEX column with sequential numbers that can be used as a primary key.
3. There are no invalid characters, such as commas.
4. I copied the CSV file and deleted the first 847 and imported it again, and it imported the next 26 rows. This shows that there is nothing wrong with the data and it could have imported it originally.

Why won't the MySql Workbench import all million rows?

[image]

Comment: If you separate the file to multiple small files, will it import everything? Does it has to do with `duplicate index`? And what is the `file size`? Does it  exceed `max_allowed_packet`?

Comment: In second attempt, after deleting the first 847 rows, it only imported 26 rows - it should have at least imported the next 847 rows again. I will test again splitting the file. Only the index column is PK and has sequential numbers - the rest of the columns are text with no constrictions. File size is 431MB - max_allowed_packet I read is 1GB so this should not be the issue.

Comment: Split file into multiple files with 1000 rows each... same issue - it only imports 847 from first and from testing importing some from the rest, it imports random numbers of rows: 243, 143, etc

Comment: Was having the same problem with the latest version (it was only showing 5 / 10 records to import which is a bit disturbing; failed due to incorrect date format on a column but msyql workbench didn't inform me of the error).

I ended up switching to [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) which seemed alot less annoying. Would be nice if [SequelPro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) was available on PC.

Comment: I wonder if its a character validation issue, its hitting a comma in a string and thinks the csv is done, or it hits a ' or / or some other character that might need termination to be used, thus it errors out early?  That or how many NULLS you got in there perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using PhpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench, I recommend you to use command-line to import csv to MySQL, especially if it's a large file. It allows you to read data from text file or import data into database
very fast, read [this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/#:%7E:text=The%20LOAD%20DATA%20INFILE%20statement%20allows%20you%20to%20read%20data,the%20file%20will%20be%20imported).

Use this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

- Add `LOCAL` if the file is located on local machine. Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293413/differences-between-data-infile-and-load-data-local-infile).
- Change `table_name` to **destination** table name.
- `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` By default, CSV uses **comma** to identify individual data value.
- `ENCLOSED BY` means double quote mark `" "` surround values.
- `LINES TERMINATED BY` specifies line-break.
- `IGNORE 1 ROWS` This command tells MySQL to skip first row. We want to use this if CSV contain column-header and we want to ignore it being imported to our table.

For further details, you can check the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: I've seen this around and tried it as an SQL query but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

I tried importing with MSSQL (Using SSMS) and that not only gave me an error but told me what the problem was! I wasn't allocating enough space for the char fields as some values had long strings of text. All I did in SSMS was change it to VARCHAR(max) and SSMS imported all million rows. This might have been a solution for MySql but since MySQL Workbench didn't tell me what the exact problem was, I already uninstalled it and will continue with SSMS and MSSQL.

Comment: I see, so it's caused by inappropriate data type.

Comment: Correct. like choosing char(50) for a field that has over characters.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the "Import Wizard" that does not work well. Better backup the database in SQL format and import it complete.
Use MainMenu->Server->DataImport

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91hRSphTzdw

Answer (score 0):

If any of the columns is of datatype double/float and has empty cells replace those with NULL or NA. Try importing the CSV.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do not use command line, it need set up environment parameter to allow you import from local csv file.

Instead use import wizard is much easier for me.
[image]

However I only import first 100 lines.

I solve it by choose latin1 instead of default utf-8

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89044

[image: default utf-8 not work, latin1 works]

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you have to clean your data, that may be the primary reason
   for the the data not to be imported from excel to MySql workbench.
2. Replace empty spaces to null from excel sheets, remove duplicates, format
   the right Data Type.

[Data Cleaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pASzK.png)

[Replace Empty Cells with Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b42ma.png)

3. MySql workbench accepts CSV type of files from excel for the
   current
   edition.
4. Use encoding uft8, This worked for me.
   [uft8 encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pASzK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone else.

But when importing .csv or .txt files that came from somewhere else and were not created in MySQL, any difference in time format will fail to be imported. I've been testing it and it loads any table that doesn't contain timedates, but the ones that do contain timedates fail.

It would be solved by changing the date format, by manually editing or writing a little script to change the column before importing it. With this changed, the import wizard doesn't seem to have a problem.

It feels almost the same as changing "," or "." in Excel.

Comment: Another one I like is when a string going into MySQL is like Bob's cats but you turn it into Bob`s cats and no one is the wiser.