# Importing CSV using MySQL Workbench. Not all records imported

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

I have to load this csv file for educational purposes.

[Movie Table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dViKX69HPKIAzK83jyQUjPUlWx1DVafc/view?usp=sharing)

It has 4803 records and I am trying to load it with "Table Data Import" choice in MySQL workbench. But, the process do not load all records:

[image]

There are no errors in log:

[image: there are no errors in log]

But it only loads 37 records:

[image]

Intentionally, I manually change the csv by copying the record 37 (which was loaded) into record 38 (which was not loaded). But I had the same results.

I look for other similar questions in stackoverflow but I did not find a solution.

Comment: make a create table ij text forma and upload the csv or past it at pastebin, i can't see why this should be so,l but check the data points you have and see if the next shows a different structure

Comment: Please show your entire schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling the past 4 hours (literally) with a similar problem. I was lucky to stumble across a similar post (linked below), where I learned that one of my columns required "BigInt" as the data type as opposed to "Int." Problem solved! I hope this works for you if you haven't found a solution already!

[MySQL workbench not importing all rows from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402612/mysql-workbench-not-importing-all-rows-from-csv)

Comment: Thanks @Bungaweeze. I already solved by using Toad for MySQL (https://softfamous.com/toad-for-mysql/) instead,. It has also a data import tool which allow me to load my dataset with no problems. When I was using MYSQL Workbech I tried by changing all datatypes I guess ...

Comment: Oh awesome -- thanks for letting me know! I'm going to check out Toad myself now as I have a separate data set I'm now having problems with, so thank you!